# Rails: Can you check the syntax for a simple string comparison method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax

It compares the actual password stored in the database (@submission.password) with the password entered by the user from the view (params[:password]).
If they are equal, the submission is deleted.

This is the string comparison method.

```
def compare_password
    if @submission.password == params[:password] # This line is wrong.
        @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
        @submission.destroy
        redirect_to(@submission, :notice => 'Listing deleted successfully')
    else
        redirect_to(@submission, :alert => 'Password is incorrect.')
    end
end
```

This is the view.

```
<%form_tag "/submissions/compare_password" do%>
<%=text_field_tag :password, params[:password]%>
<%=submit_tag "Delete"%>
<%end%>
```

Execution error I get is this.

```
undefined method `password' for nil:NilClass
```

edit

Originally my routes.rb looked like this

```
resources :submissions do
    collection do 

        post :compare_password
    end
end
```

Now I changed to

```
resources :submissions do
    member do 

        post :compare_password
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you storing actual passwords in your database?

Comment: Yes. The submissions are not stored in the database permanently and I will be deleting them on weekly basis or so. So loss of them isn't much of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@submission is nil - you need to find this before checking the password value -

```
def compare_password
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:id]) # it is nil till you get it here
    if @submission && (@submission.password == params[:password])
        @submission.destroy
        redirect_to(@submission, :notice => 'Listing deleted successfully')
    else
        redirect_to(@submission, :alert => 'Password is incorrect.')
    end
end
```

Comment: Yeah.. I am not sure why it's nil, because I didn't set it to nil anywhere. I'm using standard scaffolding. Under "def create", I randomly generate password "@submission.password = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(16)"

Comment: Ah - I see it now - this line ' @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])' needs to be before the comparison.

Comment: I'm getting "Couldn't find Submission without an ID".

Comment: @garbage collection -- you need to make your compare_password a member route instead of collection so that your form_tag can have an action like: /submissions/1/compare_password ..that will give you your params[:id] ... otherwise you need a hidden field or something that passes the id of the submission you're trying to destroy to the controller.